# Jpa query with distinct and not null

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

How to write jpa query with `distinct` and `not null` in spring boot? Below is the example.

Employee Entity Class
sql query is:

```sql
select distinct job from emp where job is not null
```

How to write above query in jpa.

I have tried `findByJobNotNull()` here `null` is working fine but need to `distinct` how to do it please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `findDistinctByJobNotNull` ? [Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add `Distinct` to the method name

```
findDistinctByJobNotNull()
```

Comment: @Rajendra then try `findDistinctJobByJobNotNull()` or `findJobDistinctByJobNotNull()

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the following query:

```java
@Query("select distinct e.job from Employee e where e.job is not null")
List<String> findJobs();
```

2. You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

Assuming that you have:

```java
@Entity
class Employee {
   // ...

   @Column(name = "job")
   public String getJob()
   {
      return job;
   }
}
```

You can create an interface-based projection:

```java
public interface EmployeeJob
{
   String getJob();
}
```

and then add the following method to your Employee repository:

```java
List<EmployeeJob> findDistinctByJobNotNull();
```

You can find additional information in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: What if you wanted to check for (a) DISTINCT on multiple columns, (b) one of which must not be NULL, and (c) to sort result?  Thank you

Comment: by the way, the `@Query` answer fails with **"Validation failed for query for method findJobs()"**, and further **Caused by Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [SELECT DISTINCT e.job, e.Name FROM Employee e WHERE e.Job is not null]**